# Where to add the answer to an inquiry that is under the <select> tag?

Tags: html, authentication, html-select, account

I'm creating a page wherein I would fill up for an account creation. One of the forms there is answering a secret question. It is in select tag then the questions are in the option tag. After filling up the form, a prompt box will appear for the user to answer the Question he/she choose. If the right input is typed, overall, the user will be successfully logged in. But if incorrect, it will be Unsuccessfully logged in.

I can't figure out where I would put the answers of the diff. questions in the input for it to be successfully logged in when the correct answer is typed in the prompt at the output. Here is the code I did. Please correct this.

---

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Test Input</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function testResults (form) {
    var x = form.password.value=='Password';
    var y = form.username.value=='Username';
    var z =form.questions.value;
    prompt ("What is your secret answer?","Type your answer here");
    if (x&&y&&z)
    {
        alert("You are successfully Logged!");
    }
    else 
    {
        alert("You are unsuccessfully Logged!");
    }
}

</SCRIPT></HEAD><BODY>
    <FORM NAME="myform" METHOD="GET">Username<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="username" VALUE="Username"><P>
    <FORM NAME="myform"  METHOD="GET">Password<BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="Password" NAME="password" VALUE="Password"><P>
   <form name="myform" method="get">
   Secret Question<BR>
   <select name="questions" size="1">
        <option value="one"> Where is your Birthplace?</p></option>
        <option value="two"> How old are you? </option>
        <option value="three"> What is your favorite show?</option>
    </select>

<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="submit" onClick=" testResults(this.form)">
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/FqFLU/1/

```
var z =form.questions.value;
var ans=prompt ("What is your secret answer?","Type your answer here");
if (x&&y&&z==ans)
{
//Logged
}
```